# pandas_datareader not pulling TSP data

Tags: pandas-datareader

I am trying to pull data from TSP.gov for the Thrift Savings Plan closing prices.  The proper code should be:

```
import pandas_datareader.tsp as tsp # https://pandas-datareader.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.0/remote_data.html

tspreader = tsp.TSPReader(start='2015-10-1', end='2015-12-31')
tspreader.read()
```

It appears that TSP did an update to their site, and this no longer works.  I was wondering if anyone found a workaround?

https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/824